# Session invalidation not happening at the right time

Tags: jboss, jsf-1.2

Am using `Jboss AS 5.1.0 GA`. I have `JSF 1.2 servlet` running on it.

I have a Customised session listener which extends `PortalSessionListener` (am running `Liferay 6.0`)

In `web.xml` of my `Jboss AS`, I have configured `session-timeout` to be 3 minutes. When I hit my `JSF servlet`, and **dont do** any thing for 3 mins, then my customised session listener gets invoked and `sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent)` is called.

Before 3rd minute if I carry out some activity on my servlet then the `session` gets extended. Then I wont do anything. This time if I watch the logs, my customised session listener is getting called at around **2nd minute instead of 3rd minute** and its invalidating the session by calling `sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent)`.

**My first question is why is that session invalidation not happening at the right time in the scenario described above?**

Also, I have configured a `session-timeout` in `web.xml` of my `Servlet`. Am using `httpServletRequest.isRequestedSessionIdValid()` method to check if the session is valid or not as mentioned [here](http://www.jroller.com/hasant/entry/jsf_logout_and_redirect_user). In the above scenario
when `session` got invalidated at around 2nd minute, this time after the session invalidation log got printed, if I click on any page on my Servlet it still finds that `session` is not invalidated yet.
But, its finding the `session` got invalidated only exactly after 3rd minute.

**My second question is why is this difference between session-timeout configured in Jboss AS web.xml and the one configured in Servlet's web.xml?**

Regards,

Vikas

Comment: FYI , PortalSessionListener that I have mentioned above implements HttpSessionListener.  And my customized session listener extends PortalSessionListener

Comment: Have you found solution for this problem?

Comment: Since its just a Servlet, I need to `implement HttpSessionListener` instead of `PortalSessionListener `. If it was a Portlet, one needs to `implement PortalSessionListener`. Also, if load is more on Server, time out will not happen exactly at the prescribed time. It might happen after few mins.